# How do you delete a block of text that appears multiple times with vim

Tags: vim

When using vim occasionally there will be a block of code which appears multiple times in a file I want to completely remove.

Take the following:
[image]

I highlighted the block of code in question. Now I could use substitute and escape all the markup, but that would be crazy. Is there an efficient way to remove a block of code like this in vim? (I know if I was doing DRY correctly I might not have this problem to begin with, but I'm not always edited my own code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the tag text object for this case:

```
dat
```

To delete all occurrences of a tag you can use the `:global` and `:normal` command together. example:

```
:g/pat/normal dat
```

For more see:

```
:h at
:h text-objects
:h :g
:h :norm
```

Comment: wow didn't known it had something like that out of the box. Is there a way I can delete all occurrences of the same tag block? Like copy a tag into the buffer and remove all matches of that whole tag?

Answer (score 2):

In the general case (beyond the given example):

1. Use [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text) mapping to allow you to search for a visual selection (more useful than you think).
2. Visually select (<kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd> - but not <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>) the text you want to work on.
3. Search for other instances of the selected text: <kbd>*</kbd>. This allows you to quickly jump between instances of the search text (<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd>).
4. Delete (for example) 4 lines: <kbd>4dd</kbd>

Or, after step 3, delete all occurences of the search text: `:s/`<kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>`//g`.

In your specific case I would do:

1. Put cursor at the beginning of the first line in the block that you want to delete: `<div class="caption">`.
2. <kbd>v$*</kbd> - Select to the end of the line and search for the selected text
3. <kbd>dat</kbd> (as Peter suggested) - actually delete the containing tag
4. <kbd>n.</kbd> until there are no more matches.

Stepping through the results manually (with <kbd>n</kbd>) allows you to make sure that you actually do want to delete the current match, before doing so (with <kbd>.</kbd>).

Comment: When I do v$* it just matches ">

Comment: I believe it does not work. Input data(bash) `for J in {2..4};do seq 5;done`. I select visually first lines 2, 3 and 4, and would like to end up in alternating 1 and 5 lines.  Whole how-to cannot be even followed.

Answer (score 1):

A plugin like my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) provides visual mode mappings to search for the currently selected text (there are many more such plugins; the plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

Then, either use `:substitute` to delete *all* matches, or recent Vim (7.4) versions provide a `gn` command that will search / operate on the next match of the last used search pattern. Taken together, you'll get the following workflow:

1. select the block of text; in your example, the `at` text object comes handy: `vat`
2. search for the selection: `*`
3. delete all: `%s///`, or:
4. go to the next occurrence and delete it: `dgn`